# Can I hold two of the same type of US visa at the same time

Tags: visas, usa, australian-citizens, visa-cancellation

I am an Australian Citizen working in US on E3 visa with Employer A and my Visa is valid till 2020.  I received a good offer from another Employer B and applied for a new E3 visa which went into administrative process and took 4 months, now I have been told to submit my passport for visa stamp.

Currently I am working on a project with employer A and I cannot leave this project for 3 months.  Can I request US Visa Officer not to cancel my current visa.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to cancel the current visa and move to the new one?

Comment: There are US immigration forms that ask if you've ever had a visa cancelled, and if the OP asks for what you suggest, (s)he'll have to answer *yes* forever, as I do.  One of mine was cancelled under similar circumstances, which are apparently completely normal and no cause for concern.  But each time I answer the question *yes* I end up having to dig out thirty-year-old passports and documentation yet again, so a consular official can confirm it's not and never has been an issue, yet again.  Best to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Did you apply outside the USA? In any case my understanding is that once the new application is approved, the previous one is voided. Make sure that is not the case because otherwise even now as you continue working for your original employer you might be violating immigration rules.

Comment: I applied visa in Canada as I am a Canadian resident.  I would like stay with my current employer (A) because of my current project.  After completing the project I would like to move to new employer (B) for which my application is approved.

Comment: "There are US immigration forms that ask if you've ever had a visa cancelled" Are you sure about that? I only see a question on the visa application that asks if you have been "refused" a US visa.